# How to use two or more regular expression for same field at validation.xml

Tags: validation, struts

I want to use two or more regular expression for same field at validation.xml!And I want to use different error message. Can we use for this code!. I want to take your advice.

```
<form name="testForm">
<field property="testField" depends="required,mask">
        <msg  key="msg1120 name="mask"/>
        <msg key="msg1121" name="mask" />
        <msg key="msg1122" name="mask" />
        <arg key="testField"/>
        <var>
              <var-name>mask</var-name>
              <var-value>
    ^(?:[！＃＄（）＊＋－．／０-９：＝？)*$
    </var-value>
        </var>      
        <var>
              <var-name>mask</var-name>
              <var-value>^[^ ]</var-value>
        </var>  
        <var>
            <var-name>mask</var-name>
            <var-value>^[a-zA-Z]*$</var-value>
        </var>
    </field>
</form>
```